# Programatically access the MSDN classes and documentation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation, add-in, msdn

I need to access the full set of .NET and Windows classes from the MSDN documentation. I've installed the MSDN docs from the Visual Studio 2012 DVD. I know of the URL method of programatically accessing classes and documentation data, but I'm looking to see if there's a faster method. I'm creating a VS addin that brings documentation of Windows API and other features into the VS IDE, and so I need an offline copy of the docs. How can I quickly access and download the MSDN documentation with all classes and data therein?

I'm currently reviewing:

- [DExplore COM API for MS Help 2 format](http://helpware.net/mshelp2/dexplore/dexplorer.htm)
- [Help to CHM](http://packagethis.codeplex.com/),  in C#

Not useful:

- [MS Help 2 API](http://www.mshelpwiki.com/wiki/tiki-index.php?page=Help2API) - no real API, just links
- [VS Help Downloader](http://vshd.codeplex.com/),  in C# - just a basic downloader of MSDN CAB files

Comment: The api is undocumented.  Buying the product from this guy at least isolates you somewhat from future breaking changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Microsoft Help Viewer 2 Runtime API Samples](http://helpviewer2.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.  It provides source code to help you get started with the Help Viewer 2.0 API, including:

**HV2ApiExplore.sln** - A utility that explores all aspects of the Help Viewer 2.0 API

**HV2Viewer.sln** - A simple HV 2.0 Help Viewer.